# How to add gradle's task parameter in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We are going to debug our Android app by adding some properties in `app.properties` and pre-process it in the Kotlin codes.

We wrote `build.gradle` like:

```
task dailytest {
    doLast {
        File testProperty = new File('assets/app.properties')
        testProperty.append("\ndaily_test=true")
        testProperty.append("\nfps_sample_interval_ms=")
        testProperty.append(fps_sample_interval_ms)
        testProperty.append("\ndrop_stack_sample_interval_ms=")
        testProperty.append(drop_stack_sample_interval_ms)
        testProperty.append("\nmin_drop_count_to_log=")
        testProperty.append(min_drop_count_to_log)
    }
}
```

And we compile it in command line using:

```sh
./gradlew dailytest -Pfps_sample_interval_ms="100" -Pdrop_stack_sample_interval_ms="100" -Pmin_drop_count_to_log="1" :connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.myapp.sub.MainActivityTest#test_click_shelf
```

I was wondering if maybe we could run this test case in Android Studio by adding some confirmations?

We did try to add `::dailytest` in the `Before launch` part, but we couldn't manage to find a way to add the custom parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `afterEvaluate` block in your build.gradle to run your task when you build your app, something like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
lint.dependsOn dailytest
}
```